# Is there an algorithm out there for creating a limitless branch of clustered nodes?

Tags: algorithm, nodes

For a school project I'm looking to create random examples of connected branches of clusters of nodes that don't overlap as per the picture. But imagine 50,000 or more of these connected clusters.

Can anyone point me in the direction of any algorithms that I could learn from?

[image]

Comment: Your graph seems to be circular connections without any other connection between the circle vertexes with some orphan vertexes added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) to allocate an area for each of the 50000 clusters. Build the cluster inside its assigned area. Make connections between clusters that share a border. The connecting line should stay within the area assigned to the two clusters, e.g. the green line is a valid connection, but the red line is not.

[image]